# C# Selenium ChromeDriver Invalid --log-level value. Unable to initialize logging

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code is not working:

```
ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions {
    BinaryLocation = "./chromedriver.exe"
};
op.AddArguments("--disable-logging", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(op);
```

Error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location ./chromedriver.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
> Source=WebDriver
> StackTrace:
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
> at WebScraper.Utility.GetChromeBrowser(String binaryLocation) in C:\Users\AB\Documents\Code\CSharp\WebScraper\WebScraper\WebScraper\Utility.cs:line 20
> at WebScraper.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\AB\Documents\Code\CSharp\WebScraper\WebScraper\WebScraper\Systems\Program.cs:line 7

Last Console Output:

> Invalid --log-level value.
> Unable to initialize logging. Exiting...

I have tried other answers on the web and have been stuck on this problem for two days now. The arguments I have added, excluding the --headless, are arguments I have tried to get the WebDriver to start working, to no avail.
Below is the directory the .exe file is within:
[image]

I have tried disabling logging using the arguments, but it still did not work. It says it needs a "DevToolsActivePort" file, but I'm not sure how to get that file or where to put it. Is it possible to have a separate browser for my selenium application rather than using a browser already installed on a computer? Have the application self-contained rather then depending on external installations?
Any suggestions will be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed two .exe files, one being the Chrome **driver** and the other being the Chrome **browser**.

Install [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/), then go to the path it was installed in (usually "C:\Program Files\Google"), copy the entire "Chrome" folder and paste it into the application directory. This is the Chrome **browser**.

Then, make the `BinaryLocation` of `ChromeOptions` the path to the "chrome.exe" inside of the "Chrome" folder you pasted. Mine was: "./Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
Now, "BinaryLocation" is pointing to the **browser**.

Then, create a `ChromeDriverService` using the `ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService` static method. Point it to the folder that contains the "chromedriver.exe," the **driver**. It must point to the **driver**, *not the browser*.

Feed the `ChromeOptions` and `ChromeDriverService` into the `ChromeDriver` constructor, and you are all set!